# AngularJS 1.5: scope.$watch inside link function doesn't update on model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

Good day **to** **everyone**!

I'm developing a **web app**, using **typescript** and **angular 1.5**;

I've created a **directive** the main goal of wich is to spy on whether user logged in or not, and hide/show corresponding element.

Here is the **link function** **code**:

```
interface ShowAuthedScope extends ng.IScope{
  User: UserService,
  _$log: ng.ILogService
}

function ShowAuthedDirective(User:UserService, $log:ng.ILogService) {
  'ngInject';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.User = User;
      scope._$log = $log;
      scope.$watch('User.current', function (val) {
        scope._$log.log('updated!:', val);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The model for my case is the current user, that being set or unset depending on whether he is logged in or not.

here is the **clipped code** for the **UserService**:

```
interface UserInterface {
  current:GoogleUser;
  signIn(options?:SignInOptions):Promise<any>;
  signOut():Promise<void>;
}

class UserService implements UserInterface {
  public current:GoogleUser;
  private _GoogleAuth:GoogleAuthService;
  private _AppConstants;

  constructor(GoogleAuth:GoogleAuthService, AppConstants) {
    'ngInject';
    this._GoogleAuth = GoogleAuth;
    this._AppConstants = AppConstants;
    this.current = null;
  }

  public signIn(options?:SignInOptions) {
    let promise:Promise<any>;
    let _options:SignInOptions = options || {};
    _options.app_package_name = this._AppConstants.appPackageName;
    if (this.current) {
      promise = this.current.signIn(_options);
    } else {
      promise = this._GoogleAuth.signIn(_options);
    }
    promise = promise.then((googleUser:GoogleUser) => this.current = googleUser);
    return promise;
  }


  public signOut() {
    this.current = null;
    return this._GoogleAuth.signOut();
  }

}
```

*The function inside $watch gets triggered only once after initializing;*

Also note, that I **already tried to pass true** as the third parameter of the $watch function

Hope for your help! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds fishy. Either you call `signIn` and `signOut` outside of the digest cycle, or you don't call them, or you call them after each other in the same digest cycle iteration so that `User.current` doesn't change.

Comment: Or `_GoogleAuth.signIn` resolves to `null`.

Comment: Basicly I test it via console: I get service instance - var service = angular.element(document).injector().get('User'); and then call signIn(); and signOut() methods and make sure each time that current changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `signIn` and `signOut` from the console, it happens outside something called a "Digest Cycle". Angular runs $watch statements in every digest cycle, but there needs to happen something that triggers it.

For example `ng-click` and all Angular event handlers automatically trigger digest cycle so that variable changes can be detected.

So in summary, if you want to do everything from the Console, you need to trigger digest cycle yourself:

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$rootScope').$digest()
```

Comment: Ingenious :) Thank you so much!